# Evento onKeyDown en un Fragmento

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

¿Cómo puedo utilizar el método `onKeyDown()` en un Fragment?
Dejo código de cómo se hace desde un Activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK){
            //Lógica
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Simplemente necesito controlar esa acción de ir hacia atrás desde un Fragment pero no puedo sobrescribir este método en concreto desde un Fragment.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Te van a borrar tu pregunta, si la editas y presentas lo que has intentado te daré la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder llamar el evento **onKeyDown** en un fragmento primero necesitamos tener acceso a dichos fragmentos desde el **Activity**. En mi caso utilizo un **ViewPager2** y en mi adaptador le he pasado una lista de fragmentos de esat forma.

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
fragments.add(new Fragment1());
fragments.add(new Fragment2());
FragmentAdapter adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle(), fragments);
```

Tambien debemos tener un metodo en todos los **Fragment** con la logica que queremos que haga la aplicación cuando pulsemos la tecla de ir atras.

```
public void manageOnKeyDown(){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "conseguido papu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Y finalmente llamados el método **onKeyDown** desde el **Activity** y le pasamos el **método** que creamos en los **Fragment**.

```
@Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK){
            ((Fragment1)fragments.get(0)).manageOnKeyDown();
        }
        return true;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

lo que puedes intentar es delegar esa responsabilidad al activity y si quieres un resultado en el fragment, mandarlo al fragment. Por ejemplo

- El activity maneja el evento `onKeyDown`

  ```
   ParentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

       override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
           // Realizar algún trabajo
           notifyFragment()
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
       }


       private fun notifyFragment(){
           val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.NAME_OF_CONTAINER)
           if(fragment is FragmentWithoutKeyDown){
               fragment.manageOnKeyDown()
           }
       }
   }
  ```

Luego el fragment puede recibir la respuesta.

```
class FragmentWithoutKeyDown: Fragment(){

    // Puedes pasar parametros si necesiitas
    fun manageOnKeyDown(){

    }
}
```

Finalmente, puedes pasar parámetros si los necesitas y el valor de `NAME_OF_CONTAINER` es el nombre de tu contenedor donde estas agregando los fragments.

Comment: Yo estoy utilizando un **ViewPager2** cuando te refieres al contenedor debe ser este o el **Layout** del Fragment? tambien comentarte que este codigo me da una exception de null, Dejo Codigo de donde me salta la excepcion `fragment1.manageOnKeyDown();`, he instanciado ese fragment1 de la siguiente formar `Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tab_layout);`